# Handling two different forms in one blade laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel application, I have two different forms to update users and user's take care person's details in a single blade(view).

According to the UI design, both forms have two different submit buttons and cancel buttons.

Currently, I'm having only one controller for both forms.

But the current way that I'm trying, giving me following [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68353678/update-form-fields-filled-with-wrong-old-data-in-laravel)

If that issue cannot be resolved then how to use two different controllers to submit two different forms in same blade

Comment: This article might help you. [https://dev.to/zaxwebs/validating-multiple-forms-on-a-page-in-laravel-8-6l](https://dev.to/zaxwebs/validating-multiple-forms-on-a-page-in-laravel-8-6l)

Answer (score 0):

In laravel applications you can use specific route for each controller method.

For example:

in your routes/web.php

```
Route::post('update/form1','UserController@form1');
Route::post('update/form2','UserController@form2');
```

in app/http/controllers/UserController

```
.
.
.
public function form1(Request $request)
{
// Your data from form1 comes here
}

public function form2(Request $request)
{
// Your data from form2 comes here
}
```

in your blade:

```
.
.
.
// form1
<form action="{{url('/update/form1')}}" method="POST">
.
.
.
// form2 
<form action="{{url('/update/form2')}}" method="POST">
.
.
.
```